# Hay algún ejemplo con RecyclerView y cardview para abrir ubicaciones con google maps

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

Me dirijo a ustedes ya que necesito una ayuda o una guía de como realizar lo siguiente:

Estoy realizando un proyecto en donde la función principal es abrir ubicaciones con google maps, para ello estoy queriendo utilizar las clases  RecyclerView y cardview, y no encuentro ningún ejemplo de como abrir en un RecyclerView, cardview google maps, es decir que se abra fuera de la aplicación.

De lo principal tengo este código (lo que hace es buscar y filtrar por ciudad)

Si se fijan en el ultimo layout verán que hay tres botones y me gustaría saber si alguien tiene algún ejemplo de como abrir esos botones en google maps (aclarando que mi objetivo es que abra fuera de la aplicación, es mas encontré este ejemplo de como quiero que abra y funciona muy bien

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:-25.318492, -57.625886?z=16&q=-25.318492, -57.625886(Mi celiaquito)"));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(intent); 
solo que ya no se como implementar en ese botón que dice ubicación, para que me abra en ubicaciones distintas )

UbicacionActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class UbicacionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText editTextSearch;
   ArrayList<String> names;
   CustomAdapter adapter2;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ubicacion);

    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ciudades);

    AutoCompleteTextView editText = findViewById(R.id.actv);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.custom_list_item, R.id.text_view_list_item, countries);
    editText.setAdapter(adapter);

    names = new ArrayList<>();

    names.add("Luque\nLocal: Mi celiaquito\nTel: 02155554\n" +
            "Direccion: La chakarita casi la plaza");
    names.add("Mariano");
    names.add("Asuncion");
    names.add("San Lorenzo");
    names.add("San Lorenzo 2");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.actv);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter2 = new CustomAdapter(names);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter2);

    editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //Despues de que se escribe algo filtra
            filter(editable.toString());
        }
    });
}
private void filter(String text) {
    //Nuevo elemento de tipo lista
    ArrayList<String> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();

    //Ciclo que busca los elementos en la lista
    for (String s : names) {
        //Si existe el elemento en la lista lo mostrara
        if (s.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
            //Añadir el elemento a la lista
            filterdNames.add(s);
        }
    }

    // Llamar al metodo filtro de la lista
    adapter2.filterList(filterdNames);
}

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
 private ArrayList<String> names;

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textViewName.setText(names.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return names.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewName;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textRow);
    }
  }

   public void filterList(ArrayList<String> filterdNames) {
    this.names = filterdNames;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }}
```

Y los layout
activity_ubicaicion.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/fondo"
   tools:context=".UbicacionActivity">
  <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/actv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:completionHint="Select a country"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:dropDownAnchor="@id/text_view_countries"
    android:hint="Selecciona una ciudad"
    android:popupBackground="@color/colorPrimary" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_countries"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actv"
    >
   </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="150dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRow"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Ubicacion" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMain2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Ver Menu" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMain3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="reseña" />
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/valoracion"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:rating="0"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la clase `CustomAdapter` agrégale una propiedad de tipo Context:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
 private ArrayList<String> names;
 private Context context;
// resto de la clase
```

A la clase ViewHolder agrégale una propiedad de tipo button y en el constructor inicializa la variable context:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewName;
    Button   btnUbicacion;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textRow);
        btnUbicacion = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMain);
    }
  }
```

Modifica el método `onBindViewHolder()` y agrégale un onClickListener al botón:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textViewName.setText(names.get(position));

    holder.btnUbicacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}

    });

}
```

Dentro del método onClick agrega el código para iniciar Google maps:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
         Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + names.get(position));
         Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
         mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
         context.startActivity(mapIntent);
     }
```

Comment: Estoy muy agradecida por tu ayuda!